# Como inserir valor no BD somente se não existir, utilizando Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tentando cadastrar um valor no banco de dados de forma automática utilizando Laravel. Estou com dificuldades em pensar numa solução eficiente para isso. Abaixo está o exemplo do que desejo.

```
    $email = 'teste@teste.com';

    MeuModel::create(array_merge($request->all(), ['email'=>$email] ));
```

**A minha logica é a seguinte:** Enquanto não houver o valor do `$email` dentro do banco de dados, cadastrar o valor do `$email`. Se o valor do `$email` estiver no banco de dados, não cadastrar esse valor. Quero encontrar a solução utilizando os *models* do Laravel. Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dá uma olhada aqui man: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Se o que importa é o email, você pode usar:

```
MeuModel::firstOrCreate(['email' => 'email@teste.com']);
```

usando o $request:

```
MeuModel::firstOrCreate($request->except(['retire_chave_desnecessária']));
```

ou

```
MeuModel::firstOrCreate($request->only(['quero_chave1', 'quero_chave2',...]));
```

sempre que nada for encontrado, será criado e retornado um novo registro.

Já com o método:

```
$x = MeuModel::firstOrNew(['nome_do_campo' => 'valor_do_campo_que_estou_buscando']);
```

caso exista algum registro com o dado que você procura, ele será retornado. Se não existir, você receberá um objeto do tipo MeuModel $x já com o dado setado:

```
$x->nome_do_campo = 'valor_do_campo_que_estou_buscando';
```

na sequencia você PRECISA chamar o save:

```
$x->save();
```

agora você persistiu e pode contar mais esse MeuModel no banco. Se você tiver $table->timestamp() na migration do MeuModel, então faça assim:

```
$x = MeuModel::firstOrNew(['nome_do_campo' => 'valor_do_campo_que_estou_buscando']);

if(empty($x->created_at)) {
    $x->save();
}
```

Comment: O método `firstOrCreate()` só funciona se os dados forem todos iguais, por exemplo se vc tentar inserir `['name' => 'Fulano', 'email' => 'fulano@mail.com']` mas no seu banco de dados já existe o e-mail "fulano@mail.com" mas o nome dele ta salvo como "Fulano Silva", o método `firstOrCreate()` vai entender como 2 registros diferentes e vai salvar o e-mail duplicado no seu banco.

Comment: Emmanuel, sua resposta foi util. Tente desenvolver ela melhor para mim te dar um positivo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar um `if` da seguinte forma:

```
$data = $request->all();

// Só vai entrar no if se ele encontrar algum registro
if (!$user = User::where('email', $data['email'])->first()) {
    $user = User::create($data);
    return $user;
}

// Se já existir um usuário você pode atualizar as informações
$user->fill($data)->save();

return $user;
```